# Azure Cost Management API does not allow me to select columns

Tags: json, azure, api

I tried to use the Azure Cost Management - Query Usage API to get details (certain columns) on all costs for a given subscription. The body I use for the request is

```
{
"type": "Usage",
"timeframe": " BillingMonthToDate ",
"dataset": {
    "granularity": "Daily",
    "configuration": {
        "columns": [
            "MeterCategory",
            "CostInBillingCurrency",
            "ResourceGroup"
        ]
    }
}
```

But the response I get back is this:

```
{  
"id": "xxxx",  
"name": "xxxx",  
"type": "Microsoft.CostManagement/query",  
"location": null,  
"sku": null,  
"eTag": null,  
"properties": {    
"nextLink": null,    
"columns": [      
{        
"name": "UsageDate",        
"type": "Number"      
},      
{        
"name": "Currency",        
"type": "String"
  }    ],
"rows": [
  [
    20201101,
    "EUR"
  ],
  [
    20201102,
    "EUR"
  ],
  [
    20201103,
    "EUR"
  ], 
...    
]
}
```

The JSON continues listing all the dates with the currency.

When I use the dataset.aggregation or dataset.grouping clauses in the JSON, I do get costs returned in my JSON but then I don't get the detailed column information that I want. And of course it is not possible to combine these 2 clauses with the dataset.columns clause. Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution without using the dataset.columns clause (which might just be a faulty clause?). By grouping the data according tot the columns I want, I can also get the data for those column values:

```
{
  "type": "Usage",
  "timeframe": "BillingMonthToDate",
  "dataset": {
"granularity": "Daily",
"aggregation": {
  "totalCost": {
    "name": "PreTaxCost",
    "function": "Sum"
  }
},
"grouping": [
  {
    "type": "Dimension",
    "name": "SubscriptionName"
  },
        {
    "type": "Dimension",
    "name": "ResourceGroupName"
  }
  ,
        {
    "type": "Dimension",
    "name": "meterSubCategory"
  }
  ,
        {
    "type": "Dimension",
    "name": "MeterCategory"
  }
]
```

}

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with getting confused with how to effectively use and filter the dataset, but I'm more having difficulty in understanding how the dataset query works. How do you know how to filter for certain things by using dimensions? I get lost in the documentation as it only gives me vague descriptions of what kind of usage I can get out of it. Do you have any sites you can recommend to learn about how to use this API more effectively?